# How to configure ADFS with react js app for sso using passport-saml and express js?

Tags: reactjs, single-sign-on, adfs, idp, passport-saml

I've my reactjs application which needs sso. I've decided to have ADFS as my IDP. How to configure adfs with my react js application. How to use passport saml in reactjs for sso?can i have detailed steps to configure this since am new to this sso concept so feeling very tough to be executed. [I've tried the steps given in this url](https://dev.to/miteshkamat27/sso-express-js-passport-saml-3b6c) but coudn't make any progress from my end. Saml request is not being genrated from my sp. Am clueless. Guidance for this query is much appreciated and thanks in advance.